# Logging.Logger does not contain a definition for SetLogWriter

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Copied code from here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/logging-block-in-microsoft-enterprise-library-6-0/

```cs
public class LoggerBlock
{
    protected LogWriter logWriter;
    public LoggerBlock()
    {
        InitLogging();
    }
    private void InitLogging()
    {
        logWriter = new LogWriterFactory().Create();
        Logger.SetLogWriter(logWriter, false);
    }
    public LogWriter LogWriter
    {
        get
        {
            return logWriter;
        }
    }
}
```

The compile error is:

> Microsoft.Practies.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger does not contain a
>   definition for 'SetLogWriter"

Sorry, I don't even know which version of the library I have installed. I'm trying to add some logging statements to an existing program that seems to have the app.config set up for Enterprise Library Logging.

Intellisense provides the following similar method only:

```cs
Logger.SetContextItemLog (object key, object value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using an older version that doesn't have the `Logger.SetLogWriter()` method.  I just installed the latest version and the code you pasted works fine. Can you update the version you are using?

Edit: It looks like the `Logger.SetLogWriter()` method just sets the default Logger to use the LogWriter you just created.  How about using the created LogWriter directly instead of the default `Logger`?

```cs
var logWriter = new LogWriterFactory().Create();
logWriter.Write("Message");
```

The following article might also give you some more information. [Creating and Writing Log Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn440731(v=pandp.60))

Comment: This is shared code, and I don't know what all the companies procedures are; also last day is tomorrow; so won't be tackling that.

Comment: I also tried using Logger.Write() without the above, but got Jenkins build error  error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EnterpriseLibrary' does not exist in the namespace 
'Microsoft.Practices' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
// using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
It builds on Jenkins, and I'm not sure what libraries they have and support in their shared directories.

Comment: Can you get the version of EnterpriseLibrary.Logging you are using?  May be able to find documentation on how to use that version.

Comment: The documentation here looks pretty old.  It might give you some clues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee778315%28v%3dpandp.31%29

Comment: I added to my answer. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I see the doc, but I don't have LogWriter as mentioned in my question. 
I'm surprised Microsoft doesn't put version number in DLL filename, so I don't know what version it is without shaking tress in the company, or maybe using disassembler.

Comment: I'm not sure how you wouldn't have LogWriter if `logWriter = new LogWriterFactory().Create();` didn't throw an error, but the next line did. Did you see my edit to my answer and the Creating and Writing Log Entries link?

Comment: It was the SetLogWriter method that was not there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190866/discussion-between-david-specht-and-nealwalters).